# How to generate a unique random number on the start of a program then get the number and call it in a function

Tags: c++, random, numbers, stdio

I'm making a small game in C++ for fun and I make a random number between 0 and 100 which is the number of threats you need to solve, that works but I made a HomeScreen() function that would be called if the user wants to go back and see the threats or type in commands, well the problem is when I called my int for the threats, it created a new random number which messes up the whole game because it would erase or fastrack a users progress. I need to know how I can get the number of threats that were generated on the game's startup and get it and display it in a HomeScreen() function.

```
main.cpp (the first place where the int and random value is assigned)
```

`int threats;
    srand(time(NULL));
    threats = rand() % 100 + 1;`

```
HomeScreen() Function
int threats;
srand(time(NULL));
threats = rand() % 100 + 1;
system("CLS");
std::cout << "| HackersBeGone | Home Page | " << std::endl;
std::cout << "Threats = " << threats << std::endl; // Here is displays another random number when I 
                                                   // need it to be the same number from main.cpp
```

Comment: OT: `srand(time(NULL));` call this only 1 time at the beginning of main.

Comment: Pass it to the function as a parameter.

Comment: Naming a variable the same name as some other variable in a different scope is not a solution to this problem. Here you have 2 independent `threats` variables initialized to possibly different random numbers. I said possibly because if both `srand(time(NULL));` were executed in the same second both random numbers would be the same. (please don't rely on that either)  time() has a resolution of a second. seeding with the same seed gets the same random number. This is related to my first comment.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a global variable to do that. Although it's not the best practice it is one of the simplest solutions. Assign your generated random number to that global variable and reuse it through that variable.

Other than that you could just use the same srand seed as in your main. But that would be unorthodox.

Comment: I would argue that the function parameter that @interjay mentioned is likely the best method.